# Expanding macro imported from header file causing <error-type>

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, macros

I have a file `input_service.h` and a file `instances.h` and in `instances.h` I have a macro, `Extends_Instance`, when I use the macro in `instances.h` it works fine, but when I use it in `input_service.h` it causes `<error-type>`.

`input_service.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <placeholder/instances/instances.h>
#include <placeholder/ff.h>

typedef enum e_keyState {
    KS_NOT_PRESSED   = 0b00000000,
    KS_JUST_PRESSED  = 0b00000010,
    KS_JUST_RELEASED = 0b00000100, 
    KS_HELD          = 0b00000010
} e_keyState;

// % (KeyDown, KeyPressed, KeyReleased, KeyUp) -> `@property InputService->m_getKeyState`

typedef struct InputService {
    Extends_Instance;  // !!!!!! ERROR HERE !!!!!! 
    // Extends_Instance -> <error-type>
    // 


    // & `(e_keyState & KS_DOWN) == 0` -> Key is being held
    // => `(e_keyState & KS_RELEASED) == 0` -> Key was just released
    // => ... see `@enum e_keyState`
    public method(m_getKeyState, e_keyState)(struct InputService *self, char key_code);
    internal method(m_frameBegun, void)(struct InputService *self);
    
    internal readOnly ALLEGRO_KEYBOARD_STATE last_state;
    internal readOnly ALLEGRO_KEYBOARD_STATE now_state;
} InputService;
constructor function InputService* service_create_input_service(void);
```

snipet of `instances.h`

```
#define Extends_Instance char             *name;                                         \
                                                char             *class_name;                                   \
                                                size_t            id;                                           \
                                                struct Instance  *parent;                                       \
                                                struct Instance  *children[MAX_CHILDREN];                       \
                                                uint32_t          children_count;                               \
                                                method           (m_draw, void)(struct Instance *self);         \
                                                method           (m_debugDraw, void)(struct Instance *self);    \
                                                hashtable_t       children_fi;                                                      \
                                                bool              enable_debugging


// & (? `@class Instance`) !
typedef struct Instance { Extends_Instance; } Instance;  !!!!!! NO ERROR HERE?? !!!!!!
```

Compiler Error:

```
../placeholder/instances/services/input_service.h:16:9: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘Extends_Instance’
   16 |         Extends_Instance;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: There is you just have to scroll a lot to the right, sorry my fault. Copy and pasting ruined the formatting for some reason

Comment: @kaylum sloppy formatting.  That `\\` is _far_ to the right.  Some lines are using tabs and others are using spaces.

Comment: In that case, please create a [mre]. One that anyone can take exactly as shown to repro the problem. You may even find the problem yourself whilst constructing the MRE.

Comment: Every time there's a multi-line macro in a C++ program a kitten somewhere gets sick. Save the kittens, don't abuse macros!

Answer (score 0):

**i may be an idiot....**

Don't include the header file that uses the macro before you define that macro, sorry for wasting your guys' time. Stupid mistake.

Comment: Great question, and even better that you found your answer! But I think it would be easier to read if you removed yourself entirely from the answer. E.g. "turns out that..."